# Mocking a service used in a filter

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm writing a unit test for a very simple filter:

```
app.filter('htmlsafe', ['$sce', function($sce) {
  return function(message) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(message);
  };
}]);
```

I want to mock the `$sce` service and verify that the `trustAsHtml` method is being called. Checking the docs has not lead me to much success and after much googling this is the best I can come up with (still not working):

```
(function (describe, it, expect, inject, beforeEach, module) {
  describe('htmlsafe filter', function () {
    var htmlsafe, $sce, untrustedString;

    beforeEach(module('ComstackPmApp'));

    beforeEach(function() {
      module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.service('$sce', $sce);
      });
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function(htmlsafeFilter) {
      htmlsafe = htmlsafeFilter;
      untrustedString = '<p>Untrusted</p>';
      $sce = {
        trustAsHtml: function() {
          // stub method to spy on.
        }
      };
    }));

    it('Should mark a string as HTML safe', function () {
      spyOn($sce, 'trustAsHtml');
      htmlsafe(untrustedString);

      expect($sce.trustAsHtml.calls.count()).toEqual(1);
    });
  });
})(describe, it, expect, inject, beforeEach, angular.mock.module);
```

However this leaves me with the following error message:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) htmlsafe filter Should mark a string as HTML safe FAILED
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '(isArray(Type) ? Type[Type.length - 1] : Type).prototype')
undefined
    at instantiate (bower_components/angular/angular.js:4480)
    at bower_components/angular/angular.js:4341
    at invoke (bower_components/angular/angular.js:4473)
    at enforcedReturnValue (bower_components/angular/angular.js:4325)
    at invoke (bower_components/angular/angular.js:4473)
    at bower_components/angular/angular.js:4290
    at getService (bower_components/angular/angular.js:4432)
    at invoke (bower_components/angular/angular.js:4464)
    at enforcedReturnValue (bower_components/angular/angular.js:4325)
    at invoke (bower_components/angular/angular.js:4473)
    at bower_components/angular/angular.js:4290
    at getService (bower_components/angular/angular.js:4432)
    at invoke (bower_components/angular/angular.js:4464)
    at workFn (bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2426)
Error: spyOn could not find an object to spy upon for trustAsHtml()
    at specs/filters/HtmlSafeFilter.js:26
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do with all that stuff. You don't need to provide the $sce service: Angular provides it. You don't have to create a fake one either: just spy on the angular-provided service:

```
describe('htmlsafe filter', function() {
    var htmlsafe, $sce, untrustedString;

    beforeEach(module('ComstackPmApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$sce_, htmlsafeFilter) {
      htmlsafe = htmlsafeFilter;
      untrustedString = '<p>Untrusted</p>';
      $sce = _$sce_;
    }));

    it('Should mark a string as HTML safe', function () {
      spyOn($sce, 'trustAsHtml');
      htmlsafe(untrustedString);

      expect($sce.trustAsHtml.calls.count()).toEqual(1);
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Guess I need to brush up on the `inject` method - I'm pretty new to angular, especially the unit testing.